# Test Scores and Grade Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I keep getting these 6 errors:

> ----jGRASP exec: javac -g TestScoresAndGrade.java
>
> TestScoresAndGrade.java: 41: incompatible types
>
> found: char
>
> required: java.lang.String
>
> grade = '?';
>                     TestScoresAndGrade.java: 43: incompatible types
>
> found   : char
>
> required: java.lang.String
>
> grade = 'A';
>                    TestScoresAndGrade.java: 45: incompatible types
>
> found   : char
>
> required: java.lang.String
>
> grade = 'B';
>
> TestScoresAndGrade.java: 47: incompatible types
>
> found   : char
>
> required: java.lang.String
>
> grade = 'C';
>                     TestScoresAndGrade.java: 49: incompatible types
>
> found   : char
>
> required: java.lang.String
>
> grade = 'D';
>                     TestScoresAndGrade.java: 51: incompatible types
>
> found   : char
>
> required: java.lang.String
>
> grade = 'F';
>                    6 errors
>
> ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.  ----jGRASP: operation
>   complete.

from

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoresAndGrade
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

      int score1;
      int score2;
      int score3;
      double ScoreAvg;
      String grade;


      System.out.print("Enter the first score: ");
                score1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second score: ");
                score2 = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter the third score: ");
                score3 = keyboard.nextInt();

        ScoreAvg = (score1 + score2 + score3)/ 3.0;
      ScoreAvg = Math.round(ScoreAvg);

        if(ScoreAvg > 100)
             grade = '?';
        else if(ScoreAvg >= 90)
         grade = 'A';
      else if(ScoreAvg >= 80)
         grade = 'B';
        else if(ScoreAvg >= 70)
         grade = 'C';
      else if(ScoreAvg >= 60)
         grade = 'D';
      else
         grade = 'F';

      System.out.println("Average score: " + ScoreAvg + " " + grade + "\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use double quote instead of single quote for your grade values. Try

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoresAndGrade
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

      int score1;
      int score2;
      int score3;
      double ScoreAvg;
      String grade;


      System.out.print("Enter the first score: ");
                score1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second score: ");
                score2 = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter the third score: ");
                score3 = keyboard.nextInt();

        ScoreAvg = (score1 + score2 + score3)/ 3.0;
      ScoreAvg = Math.round(ScoreAvg);

        if(ScoreAvg > 100)
             grade = "?";
        else if(ScoreAvg >= 90)
         grade = "A";
      else if(ScoreAvg >= 80)
         grade = "B";
        else if(ScoreAvg >= 70)
         grade = "C";
      else if(ScoreAvg >= 60)
         grade = "D";
      else
         grade = "F";

      System.out.println("Average score: " + ScoreAvg + " " + grade + "\n");
   }
}
```

This is because grade is `String` not `char`. " " for `String` and ' ' is for `char`

Answer (score 1):

> incompatible types

error is happening because you are trying to assign a char value to a String:

```
     grade = '?';
```

You need to use double quotes(`""`) with `String` instead of single quotes(`'`). Single quotes are used for `char` types.

Change this and other strings accordingly form :

```
     grade = '?';
```

to

```
     grade = "?";
```

or you can change the `grade` type to `char` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning character literals to your strings when you are using single quotes.'

```
grade = 'A'; //not legal
grade = "A"; //legal
```

It's just one of those things you have to memorize about Java. Characters are single quotes, Strings are double.

But keep in mind, Strings are objects and must be compared properly. You cannot just do `s == r` for strings. To compare strings, write

```
grade.equals("A");
```

Comment: Java is a fickle beast, at times.

Answer (score 0):

String literals use double quotes, so:

```
grade = "A";
```

Answer (score 0):

grade is defined as a String, not a char - you should use String literals, denoted by **double quotes**.

E.g., instead of `grade = 'A'`, you should use `grade = "A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Either change

```
String grade; to char grade;
```

OR

Change

```
grade = 'F'; to grade = "F";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the grade data type to char or put your literals in double quotes instead of single quotes as shown below

```
if(ScoreAvg > 100)
             grade = "?";
        else if(ScoreAvg >= 90)
         grade = "A";
```